# open website on already opened edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge

Sub Resolve()

```
Dim obj As New WebDriver
obj.Start "Edge", ""
obj.Get "Www.google.com"
```

open website to already opened edge browser not to open new one

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot connect to an existing Edge session using VBA. This is due to a rather old version of Selenium which VBA uses to automate browsers. In newer versions of Selenium, you can use **remote debugging** to connect to an existing browser, but you'll have to try other languages like Python and Java.